# Failed system update and waydroid error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS and when i try updating i recieve this error:

```
When i try updating I recieve this error 



 404  Not Found [IP: 205.185.118.53 443]
```

Reading package lists... Done
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://repo.waydro.id jimmy Release' does not have a Release file.

I have tried to look for the repository in the source list but its not there,Any suggestions?

Comment: You've already asked this; you've got a *typo* in your sources (*jimmy* is not a codename for any Ubuntu release; it's *jammy*) and your added source doesn't follow Debian/Ubuntu standards so check why you added it as you may have incorrectly followed instructions.  Refer your prior question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488441/failed-update-in-ubuntu-22-04-3-lts

Comment: Sources added by users using `add-apt-repository` and like commands are found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which is an empty directory in a clean install (*so anything in there was added after initial install*). Sources is more than the single file don't forget.